# Show differences between two DataTables in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datatable

I need to show differences between two DataTables in C#. Lets assume that I have two DataTables

Table 1

```
id       Name           Amount    Address      
1        Product1       500       ad1
2        Product2       600       ad2 
3        Product3       700       ad3
4        Product4       800       ad4
```

Table 2

```
id       Name           Amount    Address      
1        Product1       600       ad1 
2        Product3       700       ad2
3        Product4       800       ad4
```

So differences looks like this: 
1 product has different Amount, Product2 is not visible in Table 2, Product3 has different address, Product4 is the same. 
So Table 3 should look like this

Table 3

```
id       Name           Amount    Address      
1        Product1       600       ad1 
2        Product3       700       ad2
2        Product2       600       ad2
```

How can I achive this with LINQ query? I saw few examples, but it seems that I didn't understand it fully and a lot of them are only for 1 column. 
ID is not important for me

Comment: Show what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: What have you tried?? your definition of different seems odd, as they all seem different bar product 4... so, be specific, try, show us where what you did and what you got and say why you arent happy with it, and what you dont get

Comment: I just want to show all rows with different values. So if I have Product1 in two DataTables with different address, I want to add this Row to 3rd DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Some join should do it:

```
var result = from p1 in table1 
    join p2 in table2 on p1.Name equals p2.Name
    where p1.Amount != p2.Amount || p1.Address != p2.Adress
    select new Product { Name = p1.Name, Amount = p1.Amount, Adress = p1.Adress }
```

Alternativly you could also implement `Equals` on your `Product`-class (or however it is called) to simplify the `where`-clause:

```
class Product
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var p = other as Product;
        if (p == null) return false;
        return this.Name == p.Name && this.Address == p.Address && this.Amount == p.Amount;
    }
}
```

to `where p1.Equals(p2)`.

Comment: CS1936 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DataTable'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
        // modified and new products
        var result = table2
                    .Select(d2 => new { d2.Product, d2.Amount, d2.Address })
                    .Except(table1.Select(d1 => new { d1.Product, d1.Amount, d1.Address }));

        var deletedProducts = table1
                             .Where(d => !table2.Select(d2 => d2.Product).Contains(d.Product))
                             .Select(d1 => new { d1.Product, d1.Amount, d1.Address });

        result = result.Concat(deletedProducts);
```